# Clang-3.8 undefined reference to `main' when compiling object file from llvm bytecode with global variables

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to implement nested functions in llvm through the C++ API. After i perform a semantic check (to assure that the program which is going to be compiled has correct nesting references etc) i define all function in the same scope in llvm and set all variables as global. I was expecting this to work but i found myself having huge problem while getting an executable from an .o file with the command:

```
"llvm-as-3.8 output.ll| llc-3.8 -filetype=obj | clang-3.8 ../library/library.a  -v -o out"
```

By using either `llvm::GlobalValue::WeakAnyLinkage` or  `llvm::GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage` linkage for global variables i get:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
>
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
>
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
>
> ...
>
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
>
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
>
> (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

Which seems to have to do with the definition of main, who in the definition of my ir code stands as:

`; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
   define void @main() #0 {`

The thing is that the same command didn't have any problem when i didn't use global variables except of course the case where a variable was used in a child function, which was the reason i tried to change alloca to global.

Help find a solution to this problem.
Thanks in advance.
Note1: I use llvm-3.8

UPDATE: 
when i removed -v from the clang command the result was:

> refined_output.o: In function `bsort':
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x4): undefined reference to`x'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `n'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to`changed'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `i'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to`changed'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `i'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to`n'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `i'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to`x'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `i'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to`x'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `i'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to`changed'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `changed'
>   refined_output.o: In function`swap':
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `x.1'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to`y'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `x.1'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to`t'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `x.1'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to`y'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `y'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to`t'
>   refined_output.o: In function `main':
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to`i.4'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `seed'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to`x.2'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `i.4'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to`seed'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x15d): undefined reference to `seed'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to`i.4'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `i.4'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to`x.2'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x18d): undefined reference to `x.2'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to`x.2'
>   refined_output.o: In function `printArray':
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to`msg'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x1cb): undefined reference to `x.2'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x1d1): undefined reference to`n.3'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `msg'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to`i.4'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `x.2'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x1fa): undefined reference to`i.4'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `i.4'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x20e): undefined reference to`i.4'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `n.3'
>   refined_output.ll:(.text+0x21c): undefined reference to`i.4'
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Where all this variables were defined at the start of my program in llvm IR as:

```
@x = external global i32*
@n = external global i32
@i = external global i32
@changed = external global i1
@x.1 = external global i32*
@y = external global i32*
@t = external global i32
@msg = external global i8*
@x.2 = external global i32*
@n.3 = external global i32
@i.4 = external global i32
@const_string_temp = private constant [3 x i8] c", \00", align 1
@const_string_temp.5 = private constant [2 x i8] c"\0A\00", align 1
@i.6 = external global i32
@x.7 = external global i32
@seed = external global i32
@const_string_temp.8 = private constant [16 x i8] c"Initial array: \00", align 1
@const_string_temp.9 = private constant [15 x i8] c"Sorted array: \00", align 1
```

I hope this helps you help me --- or else find the problem in my IR code generation.

I'm looking forward to it..

Comment: void main? Are you sure?

Comment: Changing it to int main() doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@x = external global i32*
```

and so on are global variable *declarations*, not definitions. Therefore, the "undefined reference" error is valid and you really need to define them.

See http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#global-variables for more information

Also note that llvm-as / llc part is redundant - clang could compile .ll / .bc files just fine.

Comment: Should i do that in every function that uses the variable or at least one (like the first one that is meant to be using it)? Secondly can you state some C++ api calls with which i can successfully make a definition? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Problem Solved! The solution is to set an initializer in each global variable using the c++ api call gvar->setInitializer(). To find how to do it properly you can use clang as follows:  clang-3.8 -c -emit-llvm input.cpp -o input.ll and after that llc-3.8 -march=cpp -o output.ll.cpp input.ll . Write the global variable you want each time as in c++ and see with which c++ api calls it is associated for each variable type.